# Join on group id, to get missing individual ids in that table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For the following data sets (super simplified):

`t1`

```
ext_id, tid, aid, aum, actions
z1,     1,   a,   100, 100
z2,     1,   b,   100, 100
x1,     2,   d,   200, 200
x2,     2,   e,   200, 200
```

`t2`

```
tid, aid, aum, actions
1,   a,   100, 100
1,   b,   100, 100
1,   c,   100, 100
2,   d,   200, 200
2,   e,   200, 200
2,   f,   200, 200
```

I would like to match `t1` with `t2`, and get all data for the rest of the `aid`'s, that join based on `tid`:

ie. output should be:

```
ext_id, tid, aid, aum, actions
(null), 1,   c,   100, 100
(null), 2,   f,   200, 200
```

I tried:

```
select (null) as ext_id, b.*
from #t1 a
right join #t2 b
on a.tid=b.tid
where a.aid is null
```

But it looks incorrect.

Thank you

Comment: @Y.S updated what I tried

Comment: thanks, posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case you can use not exists to get what you want.

I'm suggesting the following:

```
select *
from t2
where not exists (SELECT 1 FROM t1 where t1.tid = t2.tid and t1.aid = t2.aid)
```

Comment: @user8834780 I noticed you posted an answer which worked for you, but this one may be more intuitive. Either way, glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Use an outer join and IS NULL operator:

```
select * from t2
left join t1
using (`tid`, `aid`, `aum`, `actions`)
where ext_id is null
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9935c7/4

Comment: this is MySQL, I am using Redshift- are you sure this works? I dont see `using` anywhere in documentation

Comment: LEFT JOIN .... USING ... WHERE ... IS NULL all very basic features of SQL-Standard, almost all execpt some very exotic and limited databases support them,  RedShit supports them too, here is an example in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Join_examples.html) of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I have 30+ records (As mentioned, this is way simplified), so it wouldn't work for what I am trying to do as is. Any way to make this more scalable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select '(Null)' as ext_id, t2.tid, t2.aid, t2.aum, t2.actions
 from t2 left join t1 
 on t2.tid=t1.tid 
 and t2.aid=t1.aid
 where t1.tid is null and t1.aid is null
```

Comment: thank you but this returns records from `t2` based with `tid`s that dont exist in `t1`. I only need `aid`s from `t2` that are missing from `t1` based on only `tid`s that exist in `t1`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct (scalable) answer that worked for me:

```
select distinct b.*
from t1 a
join t2 b on a.tid=b.tid
left join t1 c on b.aid=c.aid
where c.aid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

run the following query to get your desired result

```
select t1.ext_id,t2.tid,t2.aid,t2.aum,t2.actions from t1 
right join t2 
on  t1.aid= t2.aid 
where t1.ext_id is null
```

Comment: Thanks Khan, this is the same concept as krokodilko's answer, however this is not scalable if there are many other columns like in my case (there are actually 30+).